# How to convert array<System::Byte> to char* in C++ CLR?

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

In my project, I pass a byte[] from C# to C++ CLR function.

C++ CLR code:

```
void TestByteArray(array<System::Byte>^ byteArray)
{
    ...
}
```

C# code:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[128];
...
TestByteArray(bytes);
```

In the TestByteArray() function, I need convert byteArray to char*, so that I can used it in native C++ code. How can I do such conversion?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
void TestByteArray(array<System::Byte>^ byteArray)
{
    pin_ptr<System::Byte> p = &byteArray[0];
    unsigned char* pby = p;
    char* pch = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pby);

    // use it...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [Encoding.GetChars()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getchars%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method

Comment: No, that would be for `wchar_t` (the C++ equivalent to `System::Char`).