# C# byte[] to C++ char* with the use of CLI

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I'm working on an application in C# and have to use image manipulation in C++ with wrapper CLI. In this project, I have a C# byte[] which needs to be sent to the C++ application which needs it as an unsigned char*. I have found a very simple example project, but his project uses `DllImport` instead of CLI. [GitHub](https://github.com/sumsuddin/ImageProcessingOpenCV)

I did search on the internet and most of the time I find people using `marschal.copy` to achieve this, but when I do this I get the following error: `Cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'byte*'`.

This is the code that I use: C#

```
Image image = Image.FromFile("Image.bmp");
unsafe
{
    using (MemoryStream sourceImageStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(sourceImageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        byte[] sourceImagePixels = sourceImageStream.ToArray();

        // Initialize unmanaged memory to hold the array.
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(sourceImagePixels[0]) * sourceImagePixels.Length;

        IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        try
        {
            // Copy the array to unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.Copy(sourceImagePixels, 0, pnt, sourceImagePixels.Length);

        }
        finally
        {
            // Free the unmanaged memory.
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
        }

        ImageManipulationCppWrapperC wrapper = new ImageManipulationCppWrapperC();
        wrapper.ConvertToGray(pnt, sourceImagePixels.Length); // pnt gives the error "Cannot convert from 'System.IntPtr' to 'byte*'"
        // wrapper.ConvertToGray(sourceImagePixels, sourceImagePixels.Length); sourceImagePixels gives error: "Cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'byte*'"
    }
}
```

CLI

```
void ImageManipulationCppWrapperC::ConvertToGray(unsigned char* data, int dataLen)
{
    imP->ConvertToGray(data, dataLen);
}

bool ImageManipulationCppWrapperC::ReleaseMemoryFromC(unsigned char* buf)
{
    return imP->ReleaseMemoryFromC(buf);
}
```

C++

```
void ImageManipulationCpp::ConvertToGray(unsigned char* data, int dataLen)
{
    ...
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to send the byte[] to C++ with the use of CLI? and if so how can I do this?

Comment: Does [this answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707985/how-to-convert-arraysystembyte-to-char-in-c-clr)?

Comment: @ChrisMM, I'm just starting with CLI, so I might be wrong at this. But doesn't the ^ mean a ref in C#?

Comment: It is a GC pointer. They're created with `gcnew` (c++-cli), or regular `new` in C#

Comment: @ChrisMM No its a regular `new`. `gcnew` isn't used in the project.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that c++ cli uses `gcnew` for objects created dynamically which the garbage collector maintains. Instead of using the `*` it uses `^`. The example I linked to is C++ cli, so the `^` in that case just means a pointer that the garbage collector will handle. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202463/what-does-the-caret-mean-in-c-cli) for more info on that.

Comment: @ChrisMM okay thank you for that. Sadly std::array expects more then 1 argument. I currently have this: `std::array<System::Byte>^ bytearray` on the `>` I get the following error: `Too few arguments for class template "std::array"`

Comment: In the linked code, the `array` is not an `std::array`, but a `System::array`. One of the annoying things about working with C++/CLI, is that `std` and `System` have a fair amount of classes named the same thing...

Comment: @ChrisMM whoops, atleast I do not get an error, but now the assembly will not load... I have traced it back to this code `ImageManipulationCppWrapperC wrapper = new ImageManipulationCppWrapperC();` if I comment it the program will run. Do you have a quick fix for this? seems a bit strange that the assembly will no longer load after just a few code changes and no configuration change

Comment: anyway `void ImageManipulationCpp::ConvertToGray(unsigned char* data, int dataLen)` <= terrible api, **what it does?** does it change something  inside `data`? does it leave the same array size?

Comment: Not entirely sure from what is given. Make sure that the C# project properly references the C++/CLI. I don't do too much work with .net anymore, so can't help much more, sorry.

Comment: It is referenced alright, if I comment just this one line the program will run, but no call to C++ is made, I will do some research. first linked said to create a new project...

Comment: Just use IntPtr as the argument type in your C++/CLI code.  Call the native function with (unsigned char*)data.ToPointer() cast.